# Node-Webkit App Crashes on Drag and Drop from Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, drag-and-drop, node-webkit

I have a node-webkit app that reads image metadata and I wanted to create a drag-and-drop feature to allow the user to drag images from the desktop or the browser into the app. Dragging images from the desktop works fine, but dragging images from the browser into the app causes my node-webkit application to crash.

I commented out all of the code in my .on('drop', ...) handler and it still crashes. Further more, if I drop the browser image anywhere on the node-webkit app even if it is outside the dropzone, it will also crash.

I've also found that if I put a breakpoint on the 'drop' handler and step through the code then it won't crash.

I couldn't find anything on the web about a node-webkit bug related to this issue but I'd appreciate any information on how to get around this!

**Edit**

Here is my drag-and-drop code:

```
$(document).on('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('dragover', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  dropBox.css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
});

$(document).on('drop', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do a thing
});
```

Comment: You should open an issue here: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues and describe more your problem by providing some code. Also do not forget to specify your OS and node-webkit version.

Comment: What specific code do you have tied to the drop? I tried recreating the issue and didn't have any problem dragging images from a browser.

Comment: @gotohales - That's curious... I added my drag-and-drop code to the question. Is yours similar?

Comment: @flapjack103 I tried your code and didn't run into any immediate issues. The code I've used in the past is usually variations on the wiki: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Dragging-files-into-page Maybe if you add the version of node-webkit and the browser it'll help?